# problema para reemplazar fs.exists

Tags: nodejs, express, fs

estoy creando una función en node js para obtener la ruta de una imagen dentro del servidor (upload/avatar) pero me acabo de dar cuenta que fs.exists dejó de funcionar y no sé cómo hacer que la función retorne la ruta completa de la imagen, intenté usar fs.stat y fs.access pero no he podido hacerlo funcionar. Agradecería su ayuda, gracias.

```
function getAvatar(req, res){
const avatarName = req.params.avatarName;
const filePath = "./upload/avatar/" + avatarName;

fs.exists(filePath, exists => {
    if(!exists){
        res.status(404).send({message: "No se ha encontrado el avatar buscado."});
    }else{
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(filePath));
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar `fs.existsSync()` que es la versión sincrónica de `fs.exists()`

```javascript
const getAvatar = (req, res) => {
  const avatarName = req.params.avatarName;
  const filePath = "./upload/avatar/" + avatarName;

  if(fs.existsSync(filePath)){
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(filePath));
  }else{
        res.status(404).send({message: "No se ha encontrado el avatar buscado."});
  }
}
```

[Documentación](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)

Comment: Pues sí me sirvió, pero ahora me está arrojando un error el servidor que dice
 Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0 y ya revisé todos los JSON.parse y nada

Comment: Posiblemente sea un problema en la respuesta del servidor.
Pone el JSON en la publicación o hace una nueva así podemos ayudarte!